# ¿Como creo una barra de navegacion flotante fixed en la parte superior con medidas responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mediaqueries

Buen día,
quiero hacer una barra de navegación flotante en la parte superior, y cuando llegue a una resolución baja (600) aplicar media queries y ocultar las opciones dentro de un icono de barra o dentro del logotipo. Me las arreglo para montar todo, pero cuando me desplazo por la página, y hago click en el icono de barras el navbar sube al inicio de la pagina. cuando deberia de mostrar las opciones sin subir

Agradezco si me pudiera decir que necesito agregar al código para que funcione o si tiene ideas más efectivas, le agradecería su sabiduría. Gracias

[image: modelo]

https://jsfiddle.net/Dottemo/9u7dnLgt/5/

```
<nav class="wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0s">
                    <ul class=""> 
                        <div class="topmenu" id="myTopnav">
                            <img class="" style="float:left; padding-right: 100px; " src="../img/logo.png">
                            <a class="home" href="#home">Inicio</a>
                            <a href="#contact">Sobre</a>
                            <a href="#about">Trabajo</a>
                            <a href="#price">Precio</a>
                            <a class="contact" href="#contact">Contacto</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                              <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a> 
                        </div>         
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

```
/** Topmenu Style **/
.topmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    margin: 23px;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 11px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 14px -7px #065158;
    z-index: 10;
}
.topmenu a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #808080;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.topmenu a:hover {
  color: #15a5b2;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.topmenu .icon {
  display: none;
}
.contact{
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.active{
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    

/**** Media Querys ***/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topmenu a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topmenu a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topmenu.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topmenu.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .topmenu.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topmenu") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topmenu";
  }
}
```

Comment: tenes como 2 etiquetas sin cerrar. Al menos en el Edit fiddle.

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques preguntas. En las últimas 14 horas has preguntado esto mismo 3 veces (además de esta también lo has preguntado [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/561635/263200) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/561674/263200).  Si quieres modificar una pregunta pulsa sobre [edit] las veces que quieras, pero no la dupliques pues es uno de los motivos preestablecidos de cierre.

Comment: En cuanto a tu(s) pregunta(s), sin que yo haya llegado a comprender exactamente el problema que expones, diría que confundes cosas. A saber: 1) Hablas de **navbar** cuando lo que estas usando es **nav** en lugar de **navbar**, 2) Cuando usas bootstrap, evita usar código CSS que puede ser demasiado intrusivo para bootstrap porque los resultados son inesperados. De por si bootstrap ya te provee de muchas clases propias para hacerlo practicamente todo, sin tener que escribir nuevo CSS. Sin embargo, al hacerlo, estas causando choques entre bootstrap y tus nuevas rules de CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me he tomado la libertad de cambiar el `nav` por `navbar`, a ver si así te convence más, y porque además ya contempla el uso de la clase `navbar-toggler` y hace mejor el tema del responsive por defecto.

Fíjate que he desechado **todo** tu CSS y el javascript, pues bootstrap ya maneja la mayoria de lo que pretendes, y lo que te muestro aquí es solo para que comprendas que la funcionalidad que creo que dices que funciona mal, si lo haces con **navbar** funciona mejor.

Como he dicho en los comentarios, **evita el uso de CSS personalizado que pueda interferir en el comportamiento normal de bootstrap**. En su lugar busca las clases de bootstrap que están ya preparadas para ello. En mi opinión, si quieres agregar CSS personalizado, que sea solo para temas de apariencia (colores, bordes, etc), pero no de ubicación de los elementos (position, margin, etc), porque te pueden generar muchos problemas, tal como ya te está sucediendo.

Prueba esto a ver si te sirve de base para luego maquillarlo con CSS a tu gusto, pero tal como he explicado antes, es decir, sin querer entrar en retoques que afecten a bootstrap:

```html
<html class="h-100">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>DevLite</title>
  <!-- Icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Google Fonts-->
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mdb.min.css">
  <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Inicio del proyecto -->
  <div class="container-fluid back">
    <div id="home"></div>
    <!--Nav-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="offset-md-2 offset-sm-2 offset-lg-2 col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0s">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img class="" style="float:left; padding-right: 100px; " src="https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link home" href="#home">Inicio</a></li>

                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Sobre</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Trabajo</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#price">Precio</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link contact" href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--Anuncio-->
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum aspernatur libero quis praesentium iste adipisci nam quidem atque fugit sit. In amet asperiores corporis rerum voluptas architecto quibusdam deserunt optio! Sapiente maiores ipsam soluta
    sit unde, debitis molestias repudiandae pariatur tempore qui nihil a nemo odio laboriosam blanditiis provident. Deserunt aliquam sint dolorem saepe, tenetur alias et enim nihil laborum. Esse molestias delectus cumque, fugiat suscipit ratione quidem
    consequatur amet dignissimos blanditiis quod voluptates dolore sed quo deserunt deleniti facere aliquid reiciendis totam cupiditate iusto debitis quia veritatis! Eaque, aliquam! Amet est nisi excepturi repellat accusantium fugiat in magnam eius dignissimos
    tenetur, voluptatem earum? Fugiat ab sint nesciunt beatae laudantium, reprehenderit, natus nulla, officiis rerum odio nobis veritatis! Quaerat, sunt? Provident accusantium assumenda cupiditate corporis neque dolore animi porro fugiat quae amet qui
    quaerat et, velit, aperiam blanditiis commodi? Magnam sunt reiciendis accusamus tempora commodi libero esse alias deserunt ut! Explicabo, aliquid. Porro nostrum quae magni, praesentium incidunt pariatur sit fugiat tempora expedita architecto rem,
    unde in, alias animi sed. Quidem odio cum pariatur officiis tempore aliquam, sunt sapiente deserunt? Cumque quas voluptas porro dolore delectus recusandae ipsum ipsa, optio dolor voluptate vero quidem? Sed ex sunt libero recusandae dicta, qui, modi
    possimus inventore aspernatur quia nisi necessitatibus molestias culpa? Quaerat cumque excepturi voluptatibus illo at ipsam distinctio similique ratione, debitis est facilis explicabo laudantium temporibus voluptate mollitia blanditiis quisquam deserunt
    odio veniam pariatur architecto magnam. Omnis unde doloribus maiores. Porro, corporis culpa fuga consequatur maxime neque nesciunt, veritatis iure molestias nisi placeat doloremque rerum eius esse? Animi cumque, tempore quos, dicta numquam deleniti
    temporibus eos illum rem, ipsum laudantium. Magni asperiores, autem esse illum architecto fuga possimus tempore. Officia quae ex, natus id rerum at aspernatur sequi quidem minima autem, hic eos nesciunt fugiat, consequuntur consequatur tempore in?
    Corrupti. Amet dolore officia harum! Omnis rerum obcaecati, expedita impedit ex voluptates ipsa! Nam omnis officiis quos facere ea. Dolor, culpa deleniti. Exercitationem accusamus maiores eaque, ab rerum non quod deleniti? Ea maiores nam, perspiciatis,
    ab beatae velit asperiores repudiandae, cupiditate eum at doloremque. Laboriosam temporibus iure, expedita quos, est dignissimos blanditiis laborum ad facilis quasi possimus fuga quas placeat perferendis. Nostrum doloremque repudiandae laborum labore
    magni eum, sint minima mollitia, commodi sit, aliquam esse deserunt dolore non nesciunt? Iusto dolore molestias veritatis ullam esse repellat sapiente tempora velit repudiandae culpa! A unde iste, fuga culpa rerum quidem accusantium sit laboriosam
    quam nihil maiores quasi placeat qui atque doloribus quo! Quae nisi dolorum quod itaque reiciendis ipsam est possimus exercitationem dignissimos. Harum, maiores deserunt. Quisquam alias, molestias incidunt in quos, sequi officiis explicabo facere,
    assumenda reprehenderit deleniti sint ut eveniet ex! Quae minus cum culpa magnam corporis earum laudantium harum ipsa. Ipsum unde itaque quam qui sequi blanditiis! Architecto temporibus sint minima velit provident blanditiis? Harum recusandae et saepe
    labore ipsum. Porro sequi aliquid optio eius sit non soluta adipisci obcaecati? Consequatur exercitationem perferendis, at doloribus expedita sunt, esse aperiam numquam reiciendis impedit reprehenderit tenetur veritatis dolor ipsum repellendus rerum
    inventore! Iste, earum quae temporibus repellat qui inventore tenetur laboriosam repellendus? Magni illum, rerum amet odit sapiente fuga error eveniet. Impedit voluptatibus libero autem reiciendis dolorum iure molestias? Animi dignissimos similique,
    ducimus suscipit deleniti quidem minus expedita corporis consequatur reiciendis minima. Ipsa quas unde fugiat, consectetur ducimus in, eligendi laborum blanditiis magnam optio sapiente consequuntur hic perferendis cum dignissimos soluta velit delectus
    et architecto? Dicta, dolore omnis? Illum, nostrum quibusdam. Assumenda. Aliquid architecto vitae maiores modi aspernatur pariatur! Quo numquam illo eveniet! Aliquam, eaque? Nostrum natus consectetur earum, esse dicta saepe. Aperiam molestias quam
    suscipit nobis accusamus obcaecati mollitia temporibus velit!
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ya lo probé y funciona como necesito solo falta una cosa, como tendría que hacer para: 
que flote al inicio de la pagina, creo que es "fixed". y que cuando el usuario toque el icono de barras no suba al inicio de la pagina, sino que mantenga su posición y muestre las opciones - Ejemplo: estoy a la mitad de la pagina y hago click en las barras, este muestres las opciones a mitad de la pagina o al final si me encuentro al final

Comment: y viendo otra cosa, es que al desplegar las opciones, baja el contenido, hay alguna manera de que muestre las opciones sin que baje el contenido sino que se muestre sobre el?

Comment: Sobre lo del fixed, realmente no entiendo lo que quieres, pero [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/#navbars) encontrarás ejemplos de navbar. Por otra parte, en este [otro enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/helpers/position/) encontrarás información sobre los helpers de posición, y por último, en este [otro enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/position/) tambien tratan el posicionamiento aunque creo que ya no es responsive. Míralos y juega con ellos a ver si alguno te convence.

Comment: sobre el despliege de opciones, [esto es lo que he encontrado](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#toggler), aunque no parece que ninguna de ellas pueda ayudarte a hacer lo que quieres.  Quizás combinando [esta](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#external-content) con algo más lo consigues. Otra opción que tienes es **no usar** bootstrap para las clases para el navbar o nav, sino hacerlo a pelo con CSS, donde lo controles todo sin que bootstrap se meta con ello.

Comment: Le di un vistazo a las paginas que enviaste y esta seria las mas acertada, la de los ejemplos, este modelo es lo que busco: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/navbar-fixed/ , ya solo tendría que hacer cambios de colores, agregarle borde y el logo

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya servido.  En cuanto a eso de colores y borde yo crearia una nueva clase en CSS y se la aplicaria, agregando esa nueva clase a las otras (recuerda, no intentes cambiar posiciones o tamaños, tan solo cosas estéticas ya está bien).  Y en cuanto al logo, entiendo que es solo cambiar el **src=** de la **img**.

Comment: Si, hice como me dijiste, y solo cambie lo estetico, el color de fondo, agregarle bordes, el color del texto y logo agregarle el src de la img. casi termino la pagina y trabaja perfecto la navbar en cualquier medida.